# interpreting coefficient of poisson regression

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution

I ran a Poisson regression in SPSS with hypothesis: increase in level of democracy leads to reduction in infant mortality (IMR). So democracy is the independent variable and IMR the dependent.

I got the coefficient of democracy -0.186.

Does this mean, one unit increase in democracy level will lead to a $exp(-0.186)=0.83$ case decrease in IMR?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. When using [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) with the default log link function, the prediction is

$$
E(Y | X) = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \dots + \beta_k X_k} = e^{\beta_0} e^{\beta_1 X_1} \dots e^{\beta_k X_k}
$$

so if, for example, $\beta_1 = -0.186$, then its effect on $X_1$ is $e^{\beta_1 X_1}$. It is *not* the same as $e^{\beta_1} X_1$, since given the [properties of exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) this would lead to $e^{\beta_1 + \log X_1}$.

Comment: Tim, thanks for your answer. what about natural log? is it the same as log?

Comment: @hans yes, in the above answer I used $\log$ for $\log_e$